# How to capture state - More flexible than BOOL but more distinct than NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am calling a method to set a state, in this case **animateState**. The state parameter can be one of a defined set: e.g. "hide", "show", "active", "inactive". So it's more than BOOL but more distinct than an open NSString.

Currently I am solving this by using a NSString and check the state using its **isEqual** method. It's working but not ideal.

```
-(void) animateState:(NSString*)state{
    if ([state isEqual:@"hide"]){
...
    } else if ([state isEqual:@"show"]){
...
    } else if ([state isEqual:@"active"]){
...
    } else if ([state isEqual:@"inactive"]){
...
    }
}
```

How can I restrict the parameters and eventually make the if/switch checks more efficient? Any best-practice for such a case?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `enum` wil do nicely here, define the `enum` somewhere in a header file:

```
typedef enum{
    AnimateStateHide,
    AnimateStateShow,
    AnimateStateActive,
    AnimateStateInactive
} AnimateState;
```

Then you can call your methode like:

```
-(void) animateState:(AnimateState)state{
    switch(state) {

        case AnimateStateHide:
            //Code here;
            break;

        case AnimateStateShow:
            //Code here;
            break;

        case AnimateStateActive:
            //Code here;
            break;

        case AnimateStateInactive:
            //Code here;
            break;
    }
}
```